# apply force to an object in specefic direction with bullet physics

Tags: libgdx, bullet, bulletphysics

I'm trying to fire cubes from the camera origin, using the cameras direction as the firing line. I would like to be able to alter the amount of power delivered in the shot with an int.

After looking though various bits of code found on the web, the following seems to be what I am looking for.

```
obj.body.applyCentralImpulse(Vector3);
```

Where Vector3 giving the forces in the X,Y,Z

The following gives the direction the camera is looking at

```
Vector3 dir = cam.direction;
```

how can I combine the dir and the required force?

many thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/bullet/BaseBulletTest.java#L218

Comment: Id looked into that before, but was looking for something else. thanks for your help,   `Ray ray = cam.getPickRay( Gdx.graphics.getWidth() /2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
   
  ((btRigidBody)obj.body).applyCentralImpulse(ray.direction.scl(100f));`  worked a treat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how it works for me:

```
float force = 10.0f;   //but any value that works for you
Vector3 dir = normalize(cam.origin + cam.direction) * force; //suppose your camera moves around
body->applyCentralImpulse(dir);
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the camera position for the force?  Doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: @SteveSmith i don't use the camera position for the force ... force is just a constant as in your comment

Comment: You're applying `dir` as an impulse force, and `dir` is set to the camera position added to the direction (and is then modified).

Comment: yes, but if you look at your code, its exactly the same, the difference is that i manually calculate the direction vector and scale it up with force, while you use the cam.direction ... the result is the same

Comment: OP wants to fire cubes in the direction of the camera.  To take your code, if the cam is at (x, y, z) 10, 10, 10, and the cam direction is (say) up (0, 1, 0), added together becomes 10, 11, 10.  If you normalize that and multiply by a force of (say) 1, you'll apply an impulse force of (approx) 5.5, 6.1, 5.5, which wouldn't fire the cubes upwards.  With my code, it would be an impulse force of 0, 1, 0, i.e. up.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:-

```
Vector3 dir = new Vector3(cam.direction);
obj.body.applyCentralImpulse(dir.scl(force));
```

Just replace `force` with various values until you get one that works well.